# Shopware 6 API - Is there any way to get the full exception in the response?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am trying to get the full exceptions in API responses from the Admin-API of Shopware 6.

If the Shopware 6 Admin Api throws an exception, it's always truncated. No matter if in 'dev' Mode or 'prod' Mode.
How can I get the full error in the Response? Or is it not possible and I need to check the logs?

Comment: Since people are upvoting it, I update my findings. The API itself returns the full response including the full exception. In my case the problem was the SwagAppSystem Client from the example implementation of a Shopware App. When I tried the requests in Postman, I got the exception.